# combining phpmailer_v5.1 use_gmail with paypal ipn responder

Tags: php, phpmailer, paypal-ipn

I have two scripts and want to combine them in one line.
I have marked the line with this comment:'here I need stack-overflow-help'.

First script:
This is the Paypal ipn responder (https://www.x.com/developers/PayPal/documentation-tools/code-sample/216623):

```
<?php 
// STEP 1: Read POST data
// reading posted data from directly from $_POST causes serialization 
// issues with array data in POST
// reading raw POST data from input stream instead.

$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();

foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
     $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
   $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
} 
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
   if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
   } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
   }
   $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// STEP 2: Post IPN data back to paypal to validate

$ch = curl_init('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

// In wamp like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
// please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path 
// of the certificate as shown below.
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');

if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
    // error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);


// STEP 3: Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment
    // assign posted variables to local variables

    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
} 
else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
}
?>
```

Second script:

This is phpmailer_v5.1 use_gmail.php:

```
<?php
// example on using PHPMailer with GMAIL

include("class.phpmailer.php");
include("class.smtp.php"); // note, this is optional - gets called from main class if not already loaded

$mail             = new PHPMailer();
$body             = 'this is the body of the email';

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port

$mail->Username   = "yourname@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = "password";            // GMAIL password

$mail->From       = "replyto@yourdomain.com";
$mail->FromName   = "Webmaster";
$mail->Subject    = "This is the subject";
$mail->AltBody    = "This is the body when user views in plain text format"; //Text Body
$mail->WordWrap   = 50; // set word wrap

$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail->AddReplyTo("replyto@yourdomain.com","Webmaster");
$mail->AddAttachment("/path/to/file.zip");             // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment("/path/to/image.jpg", "new.jpg"); // attachment
$mail->AddAddress("username@domain.com","First Last"); //here I need stackoverflow-help
$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message has been sent";
}
?>
```

I have `class.smtp` and `class.phpmailer` in the same folder.use_gmail.php is tested and working and sending emails.But only when I write the destination email address in this line:

```
$mail->AddAddress("username@domain.com","First Last");
```

I want to send the email to the customer who just made the payment.How can I  get the destination e-mail address from Paypal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our ecommerce configuration, we used a trick to make the real user email ( e.g. the one that he used to register into our clients database ) be sent by the IPN responder.

When a user pays with Paypal, a form is sent to the Paypal system with informations about the amount of the payment, url bridges and so on. Here's an example:

```
<form name="autoPayFormSubmit" id="autoPayFormSubmit" method="post" action="https://securepayments.paypal.com/cgi-bin/acquiringweb"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_hosted-payment" />
    <input type="hidden" name="subtotal" value="#SUBTOTAL#" />
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="#SHIPCOST#" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="#NUMBEROFBUSINESS#" />
    <input type="hidden" name="paymentaction" value="sale" />
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value=" ## USE ME TO TRICK THE SYSTEM ##" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR" />
    <input type="hidden" name="shopping_url" value="http://yourwebsite.domain/##" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Go back to the shopping" />
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://yourwebsite.domain/##" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://yourwebsite.domain/##" />
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://yourwebsite.domain/##" />
    <input type="submit" value="PAYPAL SAFE PAYMENT" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#CEE4F2';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#EAF2F6';" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; padding: 10px 5px; border-radius: 10px; background: #EAF2F6 none no-repeat scroll 0 0; box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #888; cursor:pointer;">
</form>
```

The "trick" is to send via the "custom" input the email of the user registered into the system, along with other useful data.
In our ecommerce, for example, we serialize an array with the user email, the order id, and other "non-compromising" values. After it has been serialized, we encode it with a crypt class we created on our own ( or you can simply use the mcrypt extension of PHP ).

Once you get the IPN response, you will also get the

```
$custom_encrypted_serialized_variables = $_POST['custom'];
```

So, you can replace your IPN listener code at step 3 with the following:

```
...
...
// STEP 3: Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment

    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $custom_encrypted_serialized_variables = $_POST['custom'];

    ...
    ...
}
```

And then proceed with variables decrypting and unserializing with common unserialize() and decrypt functions.

Along with the other useful data you may send with the "custom" variable in the paypal checkout form, send the client's email and you're done!

P.S: I know this solution is not optimal and maybe there are alternative solutions, but I found this one quick and efficient. Hints and corrections are appreciated!